# python code continuation from current code

Tags: python, import

I am trying to import code from two.py file thats a continuation of my current code on `one.py`, but keeps giving me "`exceptions.NameError: name 'main' is not defined`" any help would be great. Is there another way for continuing the code on `anotherfile.py`?

### examples of one.py:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from crawler.items import CrawlertItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import SitemapSpider
from scrapy.log import *
from crawler.settings import *
from crawler.items import *
from urlparse import urlparse
import re

class GottaRent(CrawlSpider):
    name = "test"
    allowed_domains = ["www.example.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.example.com"]
    rules = [
        Rule(
            SgmlLinkExtractor(
                allow=(),
                deny=(r'/files/',)
            ),
            callback ="parse",
            follow=True
        )
    ]

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    main = hxs.xpath("//body")
    for main in main:
        item = CrawlertItem()
        item['title'] = ''.join(main.xpath("//title//text()").extract())
        import sys, os
        sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('C:\crawler\__init__')) 
        from two import *
        yield item
```

### examples of two.py:

```
item['address'] = ''.join(main.xpath("//address//text()").extract())
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you should do all your imports in the beginning of the file, and not inside loop. Your example of `two.py` throws that error because module does not contain variable `main` (and `item` is also missing).

When importing other file it should contain only functions and classes that you can use in another files. You should not just "continue" code to other file, but instead you can move groups of related functions or classes there.

Comment: how would I be able to move the classes or functions?